# Need help diagnosing oscilloscope results, newbie question about clock signals

Tags: oscilloscope

I'm a newbie, and I don't fully understand the results my oscilloscope is giving me.

I'm attempting to create a crystal oscillator circuit with a square wave. I've already generated a perfect 8MHz wave using a very basic circuit as shown (using a 4001 inverter):
[image]

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fgoB0d.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

This generates a nice clean signal in yellow:
[image]

However when I connect the output to a Schmitt trigger (74HC14), I get the following:
[image]

Obviously I have some overshoot issues to deal with on the 
[blue] schmitt trigger signal and I think I understand this to some extent (lack of damping circuit), but what is really confusing me is why the yellow clock signal is also messed up? The peaks and troughs align. In my mind, the signals are two different steps/electrical stages, but they are obviously highly correlated. What's going on?

[image: Breadboard version of circuit]

Comment: Your schmitt trigger is loading the signal, you need a very high-impedance buffer on the output of a Pierce oscillator to avoid loading it.

Comment: It could be anything. Describe the setup in more detail, take a picture, draw the actual schematic. We can't determine from current description if there is just long ground leads messing the measurement or lack of bypass capacitors.

Comment: The CMOS Schmitt Trigger will  add more jitter. The >60MHz~ ringing is due to too long ground clip on probe. Pay attention to ground geometry, track impedance and load capacitance for rise time limits and other signal distortions. Are you  wanting 25 or 50 ohm drivers

Comment: Your overshoot/undershoot is classic scope probe problems. Specifically, the ground lead is too long, and may be connected to the circuit somewhere other than at the power lead of the 4001. Minimizing ground lead inductance is really important if you're going to look at high-speed signals, and an 8 MHz square wave is just inside that territory.

Comment: Thank you all for your suggestions and comments. I will research solutions and post again with results. I don't understand a few things you've said, but that's ok because you've all pushed me in the right direction which is exactly what I wanted - thank you.

Comment: The essence of the comments is that you must keep all your connections as short as possible to minimize unwanted inductance. First step would be to use short wires for your bread board connections instead of the standard jumper wires seen in your picture :)

Answer (score 1):

I don't see *any* supply rail capacitors on your breadboard. You need to add at least 100 nF of capacitance close to each digital IC on that breadboard, located as close as possible to the IC's VCC pin.

The first circuit has a "smooth" signal with a slowly varying load and is not really affected by this (or at least you won't see how unless you compare them). When you add a Schmitt-trigger this changes. The Schmitt-trigger will draw a lot of current in a very short time in order to drive the output high and low. This will cause the voltage rails to dip and ring, and that will affect the whole circuit.